# Problems adding an ObjectDataProvider in resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, objectdataprovider

I'm setting up some things in XAML, but for some reason, I'm having an issue. I'm trying to add an ObjectDataProvider to my resources, but when I'm doing that, I get this warning on my resourcedictionnary saying i cannot have multiple items in a resourcedictionnary if they don't all have key attribute in it. So I add a key to resourcedictionnary, but then I have a problem on my dynamic resource in my contentcontrol. It says it cannot resolve "DefaultEmptyPane". Then I add a reference to the key of the resourcedictionnary, but then there's some kinda of mismatch.

Is there anyone who's seeing the issue here?
Below is the XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!--<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="projectList" MethodName=""/>-->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Panes/DefaultEmptyPane.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:PopulationNameGetNameOnlyConverter x:Key="PopulationNameGetNameOnlyConverter"/>
        <local:PopulationNameGetNumberOfTestsConverter x:Key="PopulationNameGetNumberOfTestsConverter"/>
        <local:PopulationNameGetDateConverter x:Key="PopulationNameGetDateConverter"/>
        <local:NormValidationValueToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NormValidationValueToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <local:NormrequestCalculatedToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NormrequestCalculatedToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <local:RemoveUnderscoreConverter x:Key="RemoveUnderscoreConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource DefaultEmptyPane}">
    <!--Content-->
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jerry, the answer lies in your XAML itself. Did u observe why it gives error for `ObjectDataProvider` and **not** for `RemoveUnderscoreConverter` or `NormrequestCalculatedToVisibilityConverter` or `PopulationNameGetDateConverter` etc.?

Observe their placement. They are placed inside the `ResourceDictionary` tag but`ObjectDataProvider` is outside it.

Hope that helps.