# Where to add ObjectDataProvider in Application.Resources with ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary, objectdataprovider

I followed [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/binding-to-config-settings-in-wpf) Tutorial and got stuck on the **Create Instance of Config Settings Class**-part. Here they just add the *ObjectDataProvider* in the *Application.Resources*. In my case there is already a *ResourceDictionary* in this context and I think this causes the problem.

My App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:config="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
            <!-- create instance of config-settings class -->
            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AppSettingsDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type config:AppSettingsManager}"/>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MainDictionary">
                <!-- also not working: -->
                <!--<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AppSettingsDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type config:AppSettingsManager}"/>-->

                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Folder/file1.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Folder/file2.xaml" />
                    <!-- <ResourceDictionary Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppSettingsDataProvider}, Path=LoadMethod, Mode=OneWay}"/>-->
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

When I run the program my *ResourceDictionary* is not loaded anymore (*Application.Current.Ressources.MergedDictionaries* is empty), without the *ObjectDataProvider* everything works fine. Putting the *ObjectDataProvider* in the *ResourceDictionary* like suggested in the post **[Problems adding an ObjectDataProvider in resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401637/problems-adding-an-objectdataprovider-in-resources)** did not help (is it different in the *Application*-class?). So where to put the *ObjectDataProvider*?

Comment: You can check the accepted answer of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150401/how-can-i-bind-a-textblock-to-an-objectdataprovider-resource-defined-in-app-xaml

Comment: Hm that works, thanks! But I have to write it at the very end, before `</ResourceDictionary>`. I just found out that if I put the *ObjectDataProvider* at the very end it works also. But my hope was that I can use this Binding already for the *ResourceDictionary* like in my outcommented code for the last entry of the *MergedDictionaries*.

Comment: You want to use a binding to an objectprovider which you're putting in resources in order to provide the text for a resource dictionary? This seems very strange. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I wanted to add a different resource depending on a setting, but I solved it now by adding this resource in code which works perfectly:)